# CSS: defining different height for the specific areas which are in same div

Tags: css

Is it possibble to define different height values in same div to draw a shape like in the image? 
For example,
I want to specify height as 10px. where width is "a". 
and change the height from 10px to 30px linearly; where width is "b". 
and specify the height as 30px; where width is "c".

You can see in the image where is a, b or c.

[image: example]

Comment: Nope, you'll need to do this with different elements.

Comment: Why not use two divs?

Comment: I think i need three divs; for a,b and c parts ? I asked this because i wonder if there is way to do that in same div

Comment: you could use one div with two divs inside them, and add a negative margin-bottom to the two divs inside, making them "slide" down under the main div

Comment: You could even use an image map: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have done this with using pseudo elements;

here is the fiddle, I hope it will be useful if anyone needed like me:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctarimli/uQQhG/1/

Here are the codes;

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#a{ 
    position:fixed; 
    background-color:#099; 
    left:0px; 
    top:0px; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 40px;
}
#a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 39px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #099;
}
#a:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top: -1.7px;
    left:200px; 
    height: 90px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#099;
}
```